# How to center text in an android view class?

Tags: android, android-view

When I have a class that extends View how can I draw text to the center of that View? To draw the text I am using `canvas.drawText` but since you can't move text after you draw it I'm not sure how I would center this text. So how would I center text in an android view class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spirit, Maver1ck's on the right track, although it's a little more difficult than that in practice. You'll need to set up a `TextPaint` and do some measurements:

```
TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER); //Draw text from center
//setup any text size or color attributes
```

Now, to determine how to center the text vertically. Do you want to center on the visible text? Do you want the baseline on center? Do you want to center based on the text top or the ascent? Text is complicated. For the simple case, let's just say we'll center between the bottom and the top of the font (note that this isn't the absolute top and bottom -- that would be ascent and descent):

```
//Do this somewhere where you can cache it -- no need to do this on every draw.
//onSizeChanged() is a good place.

FontMetrics metrics = paint.getFontMetrics();
float height = Math.abs(metrics.top - metrics.bottom);
float x = getWidth() / 2;
float y = (getHeight() / 2) + (height / 2);
```

Then, in your `onDraw()`:

```
canvas.drawText("My Text", x, y, paint);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Paint mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setARGB(200, 254, 0, 0); //example
mPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
int positionX = (canvas.getWidth() / 2);
int positionY = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((mPaint.descent() + mPaint.ascent()) / 2)) ;
canvas.drawText("Hello", positionX, positionY, mPaint);
```

Comment: But wouldn't that just center the location from where the text starts not the whole text?